# Python FFMPEG AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'proc'

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, popen

I'm working on a tensorflow project that learns from an audio stream. I'm trying to open an audio file and store the data in an array using FFMPEG. I'm following the tutorial [here](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/10/04/read-and-write-audio-files-in-python-using-ffmpeg/)

My code looks like this:

```
import subprocess as sp
FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg"
try:
    if image_file != 'train/rock/.DS_Store':
        command = [FFMPEG_BIN,
            '-i', image_file,
            '-f', 's16le',
            '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le',
            '-ar', '44100',
            '-ac', '2',
            'output.png']
        pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)
        # pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE)
        raw_audio = pipe.proc.stdout.read(88200*4)
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'proc'
```

Comment: Maybe this is related to version number of subprocess module?

For me doing `raw_audio=pipe.stdout.read(88200*4)` seems to work. Maybe that works for you?

Comment: The "proc" is bogus, remove it.  Using `read()` like this is not recommended anyway - `communicate()` is preferred.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Answer (score 1):

I am working with `ffmpeg` and `pyaudio`. This code works for me.

```
import pyaudio   
import subprocess as sp  
import numpy  
command = [ 'ffmpeg',
        '-i', "Filename", # I used a url stream 
    '-loglevel','error',
        '-f', 's16le',
        '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le',
        '-ar', '44100', # ouput will have 44100 Hz
        '-ac', '2', # stereo (set to '1' for mono)
        '-']  
pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)  
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  #PyAudio helps to reproduce raw data in pipe.  
stream = p.open(format = pyaudio.paInt16,
                channels = 2,
                rate = 44100,
                output = True)  
while True:  
    raw_audio = pipe.stdout.read(44100*2) #get raw data   
    stream.write(raw_audio) # reproduce  
    # Convert raw data in array with numpy  
    audio_array = numpy.fromstring(raw_audio, dtype="int16")  
    audio_array = audio_array.reshape((len(audio_array)/2,2))  
stream.stop_stream()  
stream.close()
```

In ubuntu you can install `pyaudio` with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio python3-pyaudio
```

or

```
pip install pyaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, this worked for me:

```
import subprocess as sp
import numpy as np

command = [ 'ffmpeg',
        '-i', 'song.mp3',
        '-f', 's16le',
        '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le',
        '-ar', '22050', 
        '-ac', '1',
        '-']

pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE)
stdoutdata = pipe.stdout.read()
audio_array = np.fromstring(stdoutdata, dtype="int16")
```

I'm not quite sure however why you're trying to convert an "image_file" into a ".png" using audio conversion?